# formdata to string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<String> encryptedBody(String secret_key, FormData body) async {
    print(body.toString());
}
```

How can display the contents of formdata?

I tried to change it into a string like the code below. How to change formdata to string?. The code above shows an error `"Instance of 'FormData'"`

Comment: Is it `FormData` from `'dart:html'`?

Comment: I use package DIO

Comment: I intend to encrypt the formdata using AES